# How to modify the controller which handles login in laravel 5.2 (after using make:auth command)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have used the make:auth command to generate registration and login pages. However, I now wish to modify the controller which handles login.

When the users login I want to make sure they are verified, if not, I will flash a message prompting them to verify their email. However, I cannot seem to find the controller that processes the login form. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 you have Route::auth(), which is shortcut to defining the following routes:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

So if you want to modify login logic, just edit `app/Http/Auth/AuthController.php`

One more useful command is `php artisan route:list` which will show all routes currently registered in your app and the controllers handling them.

I suggest you to further read the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-routing).

Comment: thanks for that. Howcome the login, logout, showloginform methods don't already exist in the auth controller? Will adding them totally override them?

Comment: @DanielPahor if you take a closer look you will see that this class implements some traits. The corresponding methods are defined in that traits. And yes, if you add the login method to the class it will override the original login method, so you can write whatever logic you wish there. The other option is to redefine the login route to use another class or method `$this->post('login', 'MyCustomClass@login');`